# Create array from TextArea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<!----SUBMIT BUTTON---->
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="getData();">
.....

<div id="rev"></div>
```

After click on the submit button, I can be able to display my required data from my database within the text area with id='rev' in the format below:

20

30

I want to push these content of the text area into an array using jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    var arr=new Array();
                    function createArr()
                    {
                            var txt=$('#rev').val();
                            $.each(txt.split('\n'),function(i,value){
                                    if(value!=""){
                                            arr.push(value);
                                    }
                            });
                    }
                    createArr();             
                    document.write(arr[0]);
 </script>
```

It seems does not work, the output on my webpage suppose to display the first element of my array which is 20. Any one can show me what did I do wrong with my code ?

It works when I changed this

```
 <div id="rev"></div>
```

into

```
  <textarea id="rev"></textarea>.
```

I dont know why div can not be used here ?

Comment: How is the code in the second block called? Looks like it's called on page load, it should happen after the document is ready, and after the #rev element has the data you expect.  What exactly does getData() do? XHR?

Comment: the function getData() using jquery to retrieve data from my database and display the data in <div id="rev"></div> after Submit button. And yes the code in the second block is called after the #rev element has the data I expected

Comment: Use `"\n"` as the string literal.

Comment: You need to use `.html()` or `.text()` for a div. `.val()` should only be used on textareas and inputs. For the first one it checks the text in it, while for the second it checks the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire function using `window.onload` function.Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){

                function createArr()
                { 
                        var arr=new Array();
                        var txt=$('#rev').html();  // use html() instead of val()
                        $.each(txt.split('\n'),function(i,value){
                                if(value!=""){
                                        arr.push(value);
                                }
                        });
                }
                createArr();             
                console.log(arr[0]);
}
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvDWJ/)

Comment: try this but it does not display anything except the text area

Answer (score 0):

I think it is beause you output only the first one:

```
document.write(arr[0]);
```

Maybe you need this?

```
$.each(arr, function(i, val) {
    document.write(val);
}
```